# Include singular search results when search for plural in Solr

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm working with Solr 4.1, and got it working correctly. I have the terms in the document which contains "school". It gives search result correctly when searching for "school". However, I want Solr to include these results when searching for "schools".

So basically I want Solr to include singular terms in its search results when searching for plural terms.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply stemming to your indexed fields in order to achieve this behavior. Please see the [Stemming Wiki Page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Stemming) for a complete explanation and an example `fieldType` to support stemming.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. This works fine. However we are now facing some other issue which seems to cause certain term empty search results even if there are document containing these terms. If we remove stemming, it works fine.. but with stemming it doesn't. However we're checking it right now and if not able to solve will post it as a different question and update you! Thanks