# solr : how to match singular and plural words

Tags: solr

I have the below words in the document 
1) Sweetings
2) Masters

Configuration for text_general

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

How do I make sure if user searches for
 1) **master** it matches masters 
 2) **masters** it matches masters 
 3) **sweetings** it matches sweetings

I used snowballporter and it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include singular search results when search for plural in Solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148749/include-singular-search-results-when-search-for-plural-in-solr)

Answer (score 2):

The field type `text_general`, as you can see from your quote, does not include the `<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>`. The field type`text_en` however does, change your field type to it and re-index your data to get the desired results.

If you are asking why and how any other queries or text content will be analyzed in Solr, I recommend the [Analysis Screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen) from the Solr Admin gui.

You can go there, type in "masters" and for the field type, select `text_en` or `text_general`. You will see that for `text_en` and the input "masters", the token "master" is not matched, only "masters". However, analyzing with the `text_general` field and the input "masters", both "masters" and "master" are matched.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with the SnowballPorterFilterFactory is it changes the words not just adds to them...

**This is from the synonyms.txt file...**
wedding, married, couple, espouse, marriage, unite, alliance, amalgamation, association, confederation, conjugality, connubiality, consortium, coupling, espousal, matrimony, mating, matrimony, merger, monogamy, nuptials, pledging, sacrament, spousal, wedded, weddings, ceremony, wedlock, bridal

**SnowballPorterFilterFactory changes them to this...**

(description:wed | description:marri | description:coupl | description:espous | description:marriag | description:unit | description:allianc | description:amalgam | description:associ | description:confeder | description:conjug | description:connubi | description:consortium | description:coupl | description:espous | description:matrimoni | description:mate | description:merger | description:monogami | description:nuptial | description:pledg | description:sacrament | description:spousal | description:wed | description:wed | description:ceremoni | description:wedlock | description:bridal)

**This filter will remove the plural versions...**

That will only remove plural words and not truncate the words.

**This filter will remove possessives (trailing 's) plural terms.**